# discord.py level system JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

[Here is a photo of json file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXTq0.png) I want to do system of levels in discord.py, here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import json

TOKEN = 'xxxx'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open(r'C:\\Users\\asus\\lvl.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        user = discord.User

    async def update_data(users, user: discord.User):
        if not user in users:
            users[user] = {}
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = 1

    async def add_exp(users, user: discord.User, exp: float):
        users[user][exp] = exp + exp

    async def add_lvl(users, user: discord.User):
        exp = users[user]['exp']
        lvl = users[user]['lvl']
        if exp > lvl:
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} достиг {str(lvl)} уровня!')
            lvl = lvl + 1
            exp = 0

    await update_data(users, str(message.author.id))
    await add_exp(users, str(message.author.id), float(0.1))
    await add_lvl(users, str(message.author.id))
    users[user]['exp'] = 0
    users[user]['lvl'] = lvl + 1

    with open('C:\\Users\\asus\\lvl.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    await bot.process_commands(message)

# RUN
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

But i have this error and i think its bout some problems in json file, because he diplicates '0,1' as str. Please just neer mind about it, check this error and heeeeelp me plss):

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 205, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 1 (char 44)
```

**Help with this pls)**

Answer (score 0):

Your file `C:\\Users\\asus\\lvl.json` is not in a valid JSON form. If you sent the file here it may help, but you need to get it into a valid JSON form to be able to use `json.loads()`.

Comment: if it's suddenly stopped working then perhaps it's been corrupted, JSON has an annoying habit of doing so. Anyhow, opening the file manually and putting it into a json validator should be able to find the location of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

JSON files won't be able to do anything without putting something in it. Empty the file, then put a `{}` on it. It should be fixed by then.